# How do I change all column values into a same value in Python's 2D-List?

Tags: python

`input_map = [ [ None for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]`

Let's say I have a `3x3` list of `None` values.
I would like to assign `2` to the 2nd column so that it becomes,

`[[None, 2, None],
  [None, 2, None],
  [None, 2, None]]`

I wonder if there is a way how to do this without using a `for` loop.

I am not using libraries like `Pandas`. Just pure `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` as such (documentation for 2.7 [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)).

```
def changeColumn(ls):
    """ Changes 2nd item in list to 2. Parameter ls is type list"""
    ls[1] = 2
    return ls

# generate your 2d list example
input_map = [ [ None for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]

# should yield [[None, 2, None], [None, 2, None], [None, 2, None]]
map(changeColumn, input_map)
```

Comment: This fails on Python 3, it is a conceptually inappropriate abuse of `map`, and it is not an improvement over the loop.

Comment: Works fine for me in Python 3?